# Why is TypeScript failing checking the return type of a function

Tags: typescript

I have a function which should return `NetworkState`; however, as can be seen in the code, the function in most cases not returning the correct type  but TypeScript gives no error. What am I missing?

**SECOND UPDATE:**
Thanks everyone for their input. I've copied and simplified the code as much as I can, the complete code is copy and pasteable to TypeScript playground. Unfortunately I have to include ALL types to reproduce the problem, thus the code is a little longer than I hoped. Please look at the last line where I think there should be an error (because of the return type) but there is none.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

UPDATE and clarification:

**Example 1:**

`const someFunction = (): string => 45`

the above function's return type is `string` but we are returning a number, thus TypeScript gives an error: `Type '45' is not assignable to type 'string'`

**Example 2:**

```
type MyType = {
    [key: string]: string | undefined
}

const someFunction = (): MyType => 45
```

The above function's return type is `MyType` but we are returning a number, thus TypeScript gives an error: `Type '45' is not assignable to type 'MyType'`

**The problem with the below code:**

in the below example the `networkStateReducer` expected to return `NetworkState` type. However, even though it returns data not conforming to `NetworkState`, there is still no error.

if we look closely to the first `case` for example:

```
case NetworkActionType.Failure:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.sagaAction]: 'SHOULD_BE_ERROR' }
```

assuming the `state` is an empty object initially, the return value is:
`[action.payload.sagaAction]` equalling some string, but the signature clearly sets that as an object:

```
  [key in NetworkSagaAction]?: {
    networkError?: Error
    networkStatus: NetworkStatus
  }
```

However, we get no error from TypeScript.

**The actual code:**

```
export type NetworkSagaAction = 'Login' | 'Logout'

export type NetworkStatus = 'idle' | 'pending' | 'failure' | 'success'

export enum NetworkActionType {
  Busy = 'Network/Busy',
  Failure = 'Network/Failure',
  Idle = 'Network/Idle',
  Reset = 'Network/Reset',
  Success = 'Network/Success',
}

export type NetworkState = {
  [key in NetworkSagaAction]?: {
    error?: Error
    networkStatus: NetworkStatus
  }
}

export interface NetworkPayload {
  sagaAction: NetworkSagaAction
}

export const initialState: NetworkState = {}

type FunctionType = (...args: any[]) => any

interface ActionCreatorsMapObject {
  [actionCreator: string]: FunctionType
}

export type ActionsUnion<A extends ActionCreatorsMapObject> = ReturnType<A[keyof A]>

export interface Action<T extends string> {
  type: T
}

export interface ActionWithPayload<T extends string, P> extends Action<T> {
  payload: P
}

export type BusyAction = ActionWithPayload<NetworkActionType.Busy, NetworkPayload>

export function createAction<T extends string, P>(type: T, payload: P): ActionWithPayload<T, P>
export function createAction<T extends string, P>(type: T, payload?: P) {
  return payload === undefined ? { type } : { type, payload }
}

export type NetworkActions = ActionsUnion<typeof NetworkActions>
export const NetworkActions = {
    busy: (payload: NetworkPayload): BusyAction => createAction(NetworkActionType.Busy, payload),
}

const networkStateReducer = (
    state = initialState,
    action: NetworkActions,
): NetworkState => { 
    return {
        [action.payload.sagaAction]: 'THIS SHOULD BE OBJECT BUT NOT AND STILL NO TYPE ERROR'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What does it mean that "the reducer in most cases is not returning correctly"? I sort of take it to mean that you expect TypeScript to be giving your errors based on how the code is currently written, but it is not? What exactly do you want to validate here?

Comment: All properties of `NetworkState` appear to be optional, so what is it that you expect?

Comment: Because `action.payload.sagaAction` is variable. So it can be anything, typescript can't check the type there. If you try same thing with a `const` you will get some errors.

Comment: @JaredSmith it can be optional OR must conform to a type. It does NOT conform to a type. Therefore I expect an error. Also made it clearer hopefully. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Eldar please see updated question. TypeScript can check return types as seen in example 2. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @jered updated the question and hopefully made it little bit more clearer. The function does not return the expected type TypeScript gives no error, that's why I am puzzled. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What does the type definition for `NetworkActions` look like?

Comment: Create a *minimal* reproduction case. Please, please don't post your actual code here unless it's simple enough to meet that definition.

Comment: Please consider editing the above example code to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask].  As of now there is a missing definition for `NetworkActions`, which is either needed to understand what's failing, or not needed because the example could be made more minimal.  Ideally the code could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it would demonstrate the issue.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks everyone for their input. I've copied and simplified the code as much as I can, the complete code is copy and pastable to TypeScript playground. Unfortunately I have to include ALL types to reproduce the problem, thus the code is a little longer than I hoped. Please look at the last line where I think there should be an error (because of the return type) but there is none. cc @jered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript can't properly infer what the return type of `networkStateReducer()` will be because you're returning an object with a computed value, the concrete value of which will not be known until runtime. In fact, you've written it in such a way that it is impossible to infer what the returned object structure will be (and is therefore impossible to throw a TS warning for).

Consider just the function `networkStateReducer()`:

```
const networkStateReducer = (
    state = initialState,
    action: NetworkActions,
): NetworkState => { 
    return {
        [action.payload.sagaAction]: 'THIS SHOULD BE OBJECT BUT NOT AND STILL NO TYPE ERROR'
    }
}
```

Here, `action.payload.sagaAction` will be of type `NetworkSagaAction`, one of two strings, either `Login` or `Logout`. TypeScript knows that the object returned from this function can have the optional *keys* matching the type of `NetworkSagaAction`, so it gets as far as checking those. But it has no idea what the *value* of the object at those keys is supposed to be. Essentially, the type of the *key* is easy to infer based on the static code as its written, but the type of the *value* at that key is impossible to infer until runtime because it depends on the key value.

Things are confused a bit for you here because the types of both values are supposed to be the same:

```
export type NetworkState = {
  [key in NetworkSagaAction]?: {
    error?: Error
    networkStatus: NetworkStatus
  }
}
```

But imagine a case where the types of both values are actually different:

```
export type NetworkState = {
  Login?: {
    error?: Error
    networkStatus: NetworkStatus
  }
  Logout?: string
}
```

Now look at the code of your original function again:

```
const networkStateReducer = (
    state = initialState,
    action: NetworkActions,
): NetworkState => { 
    return {
        [action.payload.sagaAction]: 'THIS SHOULD BE OBJECT BUT NOT AND STILL NO TYPE ERROR'
    }
}
```

Is the return type of this function valid, or invalid? If the value of `action.payload.sagaAction` is `Login` then it's invalid because instead of a string it should be an object. But if the value is `Logout` then the return type is valid, because a string is ok. So which is it? Who knows! (until runtime)

Now in theory you might think that TypeScript *should* be able to infer this if the code is written such that it guarantees that all keys of the object would have the same type. We could even make it more explicit by doing this:

```
export type NetworkSagaActionValue = {
  error?: Error
  networkStatus: NetworkStatus
}

export type NetworkState = {
  [key in NetworkSagaAction]?: NetworkSagaActionValue
}
```

But that does not seem to solve the issue. There may be some very smart, complicated, and intentional reason by the TS devs for why this does not work. Or perhaps it is just an oversight or bug that will be fixed in the future.

For now I see you having two main options, and they both involve simply changing your `networkStateReducer()` function slightly.

You could enforce the type of the object values separately from the function return like this:

```
const networkStateReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: NetworkActions,
): NetworkState => { 
  const returnValue: NetworkSagaActionValue = 'THIS SHOULD BE OBJECT BUT NOT AND STILL NO TYPE ERROR';
  // 'returnValue' errors because types don't match
  return {
      [action.payload.sagaAction]: returnValue
  }
}
```

Or, a bit more wordy but could be better depending on your needs - simply check the value of `action.payload.sagaAction` and branch from there, allowing you to explicitly define the returned objects individually:

```
const networkStateReducer = (
    state = initialState,
    action: NetworkActions,
): NetworkState => { 
  switch (action.payload.sagaAction) {
    case "Login":
      return {Login: 'THIS SHOULD BE OBJECT BUT NOT AND STILL NO TYPE ERROR'};
      // above return errors because types don't match
    case "Logout":
      return {Logout: {networkStatus: 'idle'}};
  }
}
```

I'd be interested to know myself if there *is* a way to solve this in a more elegant way with only computed values, but as far as I know there is none.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation where you made the return types different made it click with me. For the proposed solutions, I am leaning towards the second but I will have to check if it is possible (code is at work). Thank you very much for your time and great explanation.